# Active pagination tab even on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have this pagination tab active on click and should be an active state even refresh. Like I have selected tab 3 when I refresh the page it should be on tab 3 no go to one.
I am not going to use onlClik event in HTML, I just want to do it with CSS or Javascript.
I tried it with Local Storage but couldn't be done. and I think it can be done with Local Storage.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://affiliation.iub.edu.pk/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-sm-7">
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="DataTables_Table_0_paginate">
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
<a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
</li>
<li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
<li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a></li>
<li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a></li>
<li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a></li>
<li class="paginate_button active "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a></li>
<li class="paginate_button disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_ellipsis"><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">…</a></li>
<li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0">20</a></li>
<li class="paginate_button next" id="DataTables_Table_0_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="8" tabindex="0">Next</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done with `localStorage`. Here is how I approached it :-

```js
const lastPage = localStorage.getItem('lastPage') || 1;
const lastPageElement = document.querySelector(`.paginate_button [data-dt-idx='${lastPage}']`);
lastPageElement.parentNode.classList.add('active');


const paginationFooter = document.querySelector('.pagination');
paginationFooter.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const isPage = e.target.dataset.dtIdx;
  if (isPage) {
    const currentActivePageElement = document.querySelector('.paginate_button.active');
    if (currentActivePageElement) currentActivePageElement.classList.remove('active');
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('active');
    const currentPage = e.target.dataset.dtIdx;
    localStorage.setItem('lastPage', currentPage);
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://affiliation.iub.edu.pk/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-sm-7">
  <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="DataTables_Table_0_paginate">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
      </li>
      <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
      <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a></li>
      <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a></li>
      <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a></li>
      <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a></li>
      <li class="paginate_button disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_ellipsis"><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">…</a></li>
      <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0">20</a></li>
      <li class="paginate_button next" id="DataTables_Table_0_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="8" tabindex="0">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Although try to include your approach as well so that people can tell you what you might have missed. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5farpm24/1/) where you can see the working.